# EsperIOSocketAdapter binding to specific network adapter

Tags: io, esper

I'm new to Esper and am interested in using it to send event data via a network so consequently interested in the [EsperIOSocketAdapter](http://esper.codehaus.org/esperio-4.10.0/doc/api/com/espertech/esperio/socket/EsperIOSocketAdapter.html)

It appears that SocketAdapter can only bind to a specific port which is fine if there is only one network adapter but is it possible to configure the SocketAdapter to bind to a specific network adapter too by specifying its IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a Esper JIRA if you need this feature.
You could also use the Esper API directly and use your own Java socket transport.